# Vacuum state after diagonalising a free Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators

The (free) hoping Hamiltonian
$$
H = \alpha \sum_i^N c_i^{\dagger}c_i + \sum_{ij}^NV_{ij} c^{\dagger}_ic_j
$$
is easily diagonalised by defining a new set of fermionic operators
$$
d_a \doteq \sum_i^N \psi_i^a c_i
$$
where $\psi^a$ is the $a$-th eigenvector of $V$ (i.e. $\sum_j V_{ij} \psi_j^a=\epsilon^a \psi_i^a$). In terms of $d_a$, $H$ reads
$$
H=\sum_a^N (\alpha + \epsilon_a)d^{\dagger}_a d_a \equiv \sum_a^NE_a d_a^{\dagger}d_a.
$$
One interprets $d^{\dagger}_a |0\rangle$ as a particle with energy $E_a$ at site $a$ (remember this site $a$ does not correspond to the original sites $i$), where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state of the new $d_a$.

**My question is:**

**Given the vacuum state $|\tilde{0}\rangle$ of the original operators $c_i$, how does one relate it to the new vacuum $|0\rangle$?**

---

So far all I could work out is that since both set of operators span the same Hilbert space then
$$
|0\rangle = \prod_i^N \sum_{n_i=0}^1 K_{n_i} (c^{\dagger}_i)^{n_i}|\tilde{0}\rangle \quad \text{for some suitable } \quad K_{n_i},
$$
as with any $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$.
So I guess that maybe my question boils down to finding what those $K$ are?

Comment: Does "vacuum" mean "annihilated by the operators" or "ground state"?

Comment: Assume $c_i |0 \rangle = 0$ for all $i=1,2,...,N$.

Then $d_a |0 \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N \psi_i^a c_i |0 \rangle= 0 $ for all $a=1,2,...,N.$

Comment: @NorbertSchuch apologies, yes, vacuum here denotes the state annihilated by all destruction operators.

Comment: @Alex I feel so stupid... I had in mind a Bogoliubov transformation for some reason, thanks.